# AWS Creating Custom AMI from another Custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hierarchy, amazon-ami

I work for a company that provides a 'mandatory base AMI' to use. I want to create an AMI that is baked with my code for my application from 'mandatory AMI'. Is there anyway to know the 'Mandatory AMI' I have used from my custom baked AMI after baking?
My Company needs to track all the EC2 instances running that are associated with the account and 'mandatory base AMI' used.

Is there any AMI hierarchy in AWS ?

Comment: You would like to know which AMI was used after the instance was launched ? right ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in AMI-to-AMI history.

The closest solution is to use an EC2 tag on your new AMI with the AMI ID of your source AMI:

Souce AMI = ami-12345678